# CSS calc property in Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, calc

So, check out the following code snippet:

```css
html {
    font-family:'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
em {
    font-style:italic;
}
h1 {
    color: #444;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 56px;
    text-transform: uppercase
}
h1:after {
 position: absolute;
 width: 70px;
 content: "";
 border-bottom: 6px double #ff6b53;
 bottom: -10px;
}
p {
    margin-bottom:60px;
}
span {
    background:rgba(255, 107, 83, 0.75);
    border-radius:3px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:5px;
}
.heading1:after {
    left: calc(50% - 35px);
}
.heading2:after {
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-35px;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading1">Some Heading 1</h1>
<p><em>Using <span>left: calc(50% - 35px)</span>.</em></p>
<h1 class="heading2">Some Heading 2</h1>
<p><em>Using <span>left:50%</span> and <span>margin-left:-35px</span>.</em></p>
```

In chrome, which is running on webkit engine, the `:after` pseudo element is properly centered in both cases.

However, in Safari, `calc(50% - 35px)` does not seem to work and the pseudo-element is aligned to the right of the element instead.

**My question is:** does anybody know why, considering Safari is also webkit based? According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc), `calc` support is `buggy` on Safari but it doesn't explain why.